# Start another application with home key disable from our activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to start an application with home key disabled ,from within our activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I saw someone did something bad - you cannot override the home key functionality unless you declare yourself as Launcher. Then if user choose you as default home key handler, you can do whatever you want...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so , you can't override Home Button behavior

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not disable home key functionality